# several times Mariadb failure

Tags: centos7, mariadb, server-crashes

I have vps with mariadb installed on centos 7

the problem is mariadb keeps crashing

I've tried so many solutions but no good answer fixes my issue

## here is my tail -60 mariadb.log

```
Server version: 5.5.64-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 466718 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3d)[0x5645fa2949ad]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x515)[0x5645f9ea87b5]
sigaction.c:0(__restore_rt)[0x7fce202db5f0]
:0(__GI_raise)[0x7fce1ea03337]
:0(__GI_abort)[0x7fce1ea04a28]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x645455)[0x5645fa04c455]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x70740e)[0x5645fa10e40e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x62f47c)[0x5645fa03647c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x5e6284)[0x5645f9fed284]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x48)[0x5645f9eaa838]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x37ba06)[0x5645f9d82a06]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x559)[0x5645f9d87fc9]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x2ec95a)[0x5645f9cf395a]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x5c2)[0x5645f9cf6af2]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fce1e9ef505]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x2e6afd)[0x5645f9cedafd]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
200310 19:52:29 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

==================
any help?

Comment: Are you aware that your version is end-of-life next month?

Comment: No actually, thank you to notify me.. any suggestion in fixing the problem without loosing my data? thanks in advanced

Comment: I think one can upgrade without risking data loss.  But, did you have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html, as the error says?  Did you run myisamchk (if I remember correctly) ?

Comment: One more thing: do you have the possibility to run your DB on a physical system, to rule out interference by other VPS's at your provider?

Comment: Did you leave out a part of the error log before "Server version ..." ?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, ask your VPS host for - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: thank you in advance and I appreciate your efforts, yes I've already check the myisamcheck and the link I followed without any good result,

Comment: Finally I figure out whats happens, >> BAD SECTORS !!!! thank you for referring me to check hardware  ... hope your contribution save others time ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess at hardware fault (failing disk or disk corruption).

What storage engine(s)!are you using?